# Homotopy of space of immersions, Smale-Hirsch theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homotopy-theory

If $M$ and $N$ are simply connected  manifolds with $\dim M< \dim N$, we denote by $Imm\left(M,N\right)$ the space of immersions of $M$ in $N$.

Let $M$ and $M'$ manifolds of dimensions $m>0$. It is true that if $M$ is homotopic to $M'$, then for $k\geq m$, the spaces $Imm\left(M,\mathbb{R}^{m+k}\right)$ and $Imm\left(M',\mathbb{R}^{m+k}\right)$ are homotopic? i.e

if  $k\geq m$, then $M\simeq M'\Rightarrow Imm\left(M,\mathbb{R}^{m+k}\right)\simeq Imm\left(M',\mathbb{R}^{m+k}\right)$?

Thanks

Abdoul

Comment: I'd like to suggest that using a picture of another mathematician as your avatar is in poor taste.

Comment: It is done. Thank you for the suggestion!!

Comment: do you know an example of to homotopy equivalent manifolds of the same dimension that are not homeomorphic?

Comment: Yes. Novikov has proved that there exist a manifold $M$ homotopy  equivalent to $S^4\times S^N, N>>1$ but not homeomorphic. I have also some examples from this paper of Victor A. Belfi :http://msp.org/pjm/1971/36-3/pjm-v36-n3-p04-p.pdf

Comment: @AndreyRyabichev The simplest examples are lens spaces in dimension 3, eg $L(7,1)$ and $L(7,2)$.

Comment: I would like to note that this was [reposted on MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/q/238703/40804), where it has received much more discussion. In general, when you repost questions on other sites, you should add notices to both about the reposting so as to avoid duplication of effort.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked and answered on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/238703/21564). I have replicated the accepted answer by Tom Goodwillie below.

> No. For example, if $M$ is a Moebius band then, at least for even $k$, $Imm(M,\mathbb R^{2+k})$ is not homotopy equivalent to $Imm(S^1\times \mathbb R,\mathbb R^{2+k})$.
>
> The latter is equivalent to the space of all maps from $S^1$ to $O(2+k)/O(k)$. Its first non-trivial homotopy group is $\pi_{k-1}=\pi_k(O(2+k)/O(k))=\mathbb Z$.
>
> The former is equivalent to the space of sections of a nontrivial bundle with base $S^1$ and fiber $O(2+k)/O(k)$, in which the action of the fundamental group of the base on $\pi_k(O(2+k)/O(k))$ is nontrivial. Its first non-trivial homotopy group is $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.